# How to display email already exists in database in MVC ( my database is oracle)

Tags: oracle, model-view-controller

This code is written in controller:

[HttpPost]

```
    public ActionResult Register(REGISTRATION registration)
    {
         var email = registration.Email;
        var username = registration.UserName;
        var pass = registration.Password;
        var confirmpass = registration.ConfirmPassword;
        var mobile = registration.MobileNumber;
        OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection();
     connection.ConnectionString System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ToString();
     connection.Open();
            OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            string query = "INSERT INTO REGISTRATION (EMAIL,USERNAME,PASSWORD,CONFIRMPASSWORD,MOBILENUMBER) VALUES('"+email+"','"+username+"','"+pass+"','"+confirmpass+"','"+mobile+"')";
                command.CommandText = query;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();return View("Congratulation");
    }
```

Thats the code for registration but i want when registering if user enter email address that already exists in database a  message should come "Email already exists".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if mail address already exists:

```
public Boolean MailExists(REGISTRATION registration) {
    var email = registration.Email;
    OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ToString();
    connection.Open();
    OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    string query = "SELECT 'S' FROM REGISTRATION WHERE EMAIL = '" + email + "'";
    command.CommandText = query;
    Object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
    return "S".Equals(result);
}

// usage

if (MailExists(registration)) {
    return View("Email already exists");
} else {
    Register(registration);
}
```

Comment: You should add it in the controller

Answer (score 0):

The MailExists method can be used to check whether the email address already exist. Instead of submitting the entire form and then checking for valid email address you can use Remote validation feature of MVC.

You can use the Remote data annotation for the model property as below.

```
public class Registration {   

[Remote("MailExists ","ControllerName",ErrorMessage = "Email already exists!")]
public string UserEmailAddress { get; set; }}
```

Please refer the link below for more details.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d87001/remote-validation-in-mvc/